# sudo docker rm- bad substitution?

Tags: docker

```
sudo docker  rm -v ${docker ps -aq -f status=exited}
```

После выполнения команды выводится ошибка 
 bad substitution

Хочу удалить неиспользуемые контейнеры docker. Из-за чего эта ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, потому что результат `docker ps -aq -f status=exited` состоит из более чем одной строки.

А вам, по всей видимости нужно вот это:

```
$ docker container prune
```